# No such file or directory error (Laravel/Homestead)

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel on homestead. I tried a lot of different commands in order to clear cache and other stuff and nothing helped.

I keep getting this error:

`file_put_contents(/Users/Victor/Sites/pft/pft-back/storage/framework/cache/data/05/9f/059f793d8b638b8c21ead7edbba382b9e9183fac): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

What I've tried is:

1. Set 777 for storage folder
2. `php artisan cache:clear`
3. `php artisan view:clear`
4. `php artisan clear-compiled`
5. `composer dump-autoload`

No idea why it's happening but I'm pretty sure because of homestead since I've just recently started using it.

Also I tried all commands both from homestead user and mac user (I'm running homestead on mac)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the underlying storage maps, could check if `storage/framework`, `storage/framework/cache` and `storage/framework/cache/data` have r/w permission and otherwise create them?